# Is there an easy way to make a ReadOnly value in a class in ES6 and up?

Tags: javascript

## Question

Currently, I am trying to make a readOnly value for my Class so no one can edit the vars and mess up the class.

In my class, the only values can be either a 1, 0, true or false and if they can edit then at any time to anything, they would be able to set the var to an out-of-scope value which might brack the code!

```
    let Bit1 = new Bit(1);

    Bit1.Value = "fdgdf" // <-- You Should Not be able to do this!!

    ...
```

One way I thought of a way to fix this was to make a function that allows you to change the value so it would not be out-of-scope.

```
    Bit1.ChangeValue(true) // Accepted Value

    Bit1.ChangeValue("agjg") // Should throw Error: "Error: Value has to be ether a 1, 0 or an Boolean"

    Bit1.Value = "hbkij" // <-- You should not be able to do this!!
```

But as you can see, You can still edit the original value without an Error!

Soon, I noticed I needed a read-only Var. I knew that javascript had readOnly vars because of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) but I don't know how to make readOnly Vars

Please Help!!

## Extra Info

**IDE:** *Codesandbox*

**Browser:** *Chrome*

**Full Code:**

```
    class Bit {
      /**
       *
       * @param {(Boolean|Number)} Value A Byte Value (1, 0, true, false)
       */
      constructor(Value) {
        if (Value !== null) {
          if (typeof Value === Boolean) {
            this.Value = +Value;
          } else if (typeof Number) {
            if (Value === 1 || Value === 0) {
              this.Value = Value;
            } else {
              throw new Error("Error: Value has to be ether a 1, 0 or an Boolean");
            }
          } else {
            throw new Error("Error: Value has to be ether a 1, 0 or an Boolean");
          }
        } else {
          throw new Error("Error: Value has to be ether a 1, 0 or an Boolean");
        }
      }
    
      /**
       * @description Swiches the Bit (1 -> 0, 0 -> 1)
       */
      Switch() {
        this.Value = Boolean(this.Value) ? 0 : 1;
      }
    }
    
    //class Bytes {
    //  /**
    //   *
    //   * @param {Array} Bits Array Of up to 8 bits (1, 0, true, false, Bit)
    //   */
    //  constructor(Bits) {
    //
    //  }
    //}
```

Comment: @ShashSinha Private != read-only

Comment: Implement the property using a getter and setter, and then make the setter signal an error.

Comment: I would recommend trying to move away from the Java mindset and keeping things simple, i.e. for now just don’t do the thing that breaks it. It’s your code, it’s overengineering. Eventually you’ll have enough experience to do things like typechecking correctly. (`if (typeof Number)` and `if (typeof Value === Boolean)` are not that.)

Comment: You can use [`Object.defineProperty(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: @ry - this might be used as a libray

Comment: (Also, allowing `[1, 0, true, false, [Bit]]` is itself kind of messy. Have you considered representing a byte with an integer from 0 to 255?)

Comment: @ry - Ops i ment to use the bit Class

Comment: It’s perfectly fine to say “don’t do this” when writing JavaScript libraries. But again, it’s very likely that neither of these types should exist in the first place and that you should just use built-in numbers.

Comment: @Barmar couldn't you simply not implement a setter?

Comment: @yifansong You could; it will allow you to assign to the property, but the assignment will be silently ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Here is an example:

```js
class Bit {
  constructor() {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'value', {
      value: false,
      writable: false,
      configurable: true
    });
  }

  changeValue(newValue) {
    if (newValue === false || newValue === true || newValue === 1 || newValue === 0) {
      Object.defineProperty(this, 'value', {
        value: newValue,
        writable: false,
        configurable: true
      });
    } else {
      throw new Error('Incompatible value');
    }
  }
}

const bit = new Bit();

bit.value = 'something';
console.log(bit.value);

try {
  bit.changeValue('something');
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
} 
console.log(bit.value);

bit.changeValue(true);
console.log(bit.value);
```

Even though `bit.value = ..` doesn't have any effect, because this property is set to `configurable: true`, it can still be deleted or edited using `Object.defineProperty`.

Another approach will be using a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), here is an example:

```js
class Bit {
  #value = false;

  set value(newValue) {
    if (newValue === false || newValue === true || newValue === 1 || newValue === 0) {
      this.#value = newValue;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Incompatible value');
    }
  }

  get value() {
    return this.#value;
  }
}

const bit = new Bit();

try {
  bit.value = 'something';
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e.message);
} 
console.log(bit.value);

bit.value = true;
console.log(bit.value);
```

Comment: What dose Set mean and also Get

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND Those are [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get). The setter function is called whenever that property is redefined (`bit.value = ..` for example) and the getter function is called when the property is accessed (`bi.value` for example).

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHH okay

Comment: Hay where would you put the constructor?

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND In the second example ? In that example you can put it anywhere in the class' body but preferably, you should put it after `#value = false;`.